# Retrieve Records which are 24 hours old

Tags: php, redis

I have Redis installed and I am able to access it from PHP using this Library https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis

I have a Sorted Set Time Series. The Values are added using the following code.

```
$key = time();
$redis->zAdd('redisKey', $key, 'sm:1:26');
```

I want to retrieve all the Records which are added in the past 24 hours. However, following code returns all the Records in this Set.

```
$redis->zRange('redisKey', 0, -1, ['withscores' => TRUE]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [sm:1:26] => 1545858900
    [sm:2:27] => 1545945300
    [sm:4:28] => 1546031700
    [sm:3:29] => 1546118100
    [sm:5:30] => 1547031700
)
```

Could you please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use zRangeByScore. It returns all the Records whose Keys falls between the Range specified. So you need to calculate the Range which in your case will be:

```
    $to = time();      
    $from = strtotime('-24 hours');
    $redis->zRangeByScore('redisKey', $from, $to, ['withscores' => TRUE]);
```

If you want to get all the records which are older than say 5 days, then you can specify the $from parameter as 0.

```
    $to = strtotime('-5 days);
    $redis->zRangeByScore('redisKey', 0, $to, ['withscores' => TRUE]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help in showing how to use zRangeByScore function and passing the correct parameters. This solved my problem.